# geocode reverse

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to call up a map and display.  I would like to add the the function to do a reverse geocode and print out the corresponding street address.  I cannot seem to get the long/lat coords passed over to the function.  How can I get the long/lat coordinates converted to a street address?

```
function getMyLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        displayLocation, displayError, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 9000
        });

        var watchButton = document.getElementById("watch");
        watchButton.onclick = watchLocation;
        var clearWatchButton = document.getElementById("clearWatch");
        clearWatchButton.onclick = clearWatch;
    }
    else {
        alert("Oops, no geolocation support");
    }
}

function displayLocation(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var div = document.getElementById("location");
    div.innerHTML = "You are at Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude;
    div.innerHTML += " (with " + position.coords.accuracy + " meters accuracy)";

    var km = computeDistance(position.coords, ourCoords);
    var distance = document.getElementById("distance");
    distance.innerHTML = "You are " + km + " km from the WickedlySmart HQ";

    if (map == null) {
        showMap(position.coords);
        prevCoords = position.coords;
    }
    else {
        var meters = computeDistance(position.coords, prevCoords) * 1000;
        if (meters > 20) {
            scrollMapToPosition(position.coords);
            prevCoords = position.coords;
        }
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the area about the watchbutton, the rest is working fine for me in Chrome.

You're not trying to do this from a file:// URL, are you?

Comment: Yes Roger, th above is working. I am trying to add the ability to push the long/lat info to the reverse geocode function and get back the street address. I would then display that street address.  This is the part I need help on.  How to get the street address.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Misunderstood the question. Here's some code I put together for a project a few weeks ago. It just pulls the zipcode, but you can get the address from it. It's written for jQuery. Also, I'm loading the Google Maps API dynamically. You could just load it directly, if you wanted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var script   = document.createElement("script");
        script.type  = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'http://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=loadMapsAPI';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    } else {
        console.log('NOTE: Browser does not support geolocation.');
    }
}); 


function loadMapsAPI() {
    google.load('maps', '3', {
        'other_params': 'sensor=false',
        'callback' : mapLoaded
        }
    );
}


function mapLoaded() {
    $('#geolocateButton').css('display','block');
}


function findMyLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                                position.coords.latitude,
                                position.coords.longitude);
            var coder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            coder.geocode({ 'latLng': latLng }, fillZipcode);
        },
        function() {
            alert("Could not determine your position.");
        }
    );
}   


function fillZipcode(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
            var parts = results[1].address_components;  
            for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                if(parts[i].types[0] == 'postal_code') {
                    alert('Your Zip Code is: ' + parts[i].short_name);
                    return;
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("Could not figure out your zip code.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're game to use an additional library, you might check out **[geous](http://rjz.github.com/geous.js/)** and the final geocoding/location example for its jquery plugin **[here](http://rjz.github.com/geous.js/examples/geous-and-jquery-form.html)**.

The example autopopulates a form using the `setLocation` method, but you could just as easily print the location:

```
// location geocoded -- print address
var onGeocodeSuccess = function (location) {
  console.log(location.toAddress());
}

// location retrieved -- geocode it.
var onUserLocationSuccess = function (location) {
  geous.geocode (location, { 
    reverse: true,
    success: onGeocodeSuccess
  });
}

// Try and get user location
geous.getUserLocation({
  success: onUserLocationSuccess
});
```